# CAS 6.5.x - Add custom fields in login page

Tags: cas

I need to add a custom field in login page and I use CAS 6.5.x.

I saw the official documentation of Apereo CAS on user interface customization (https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.5.x/ux/User-Interface-Customization-Views.html#custom-fields) and Fawnoos blog (https://fawnoos.com/2019/02/25/cas61-custom-login-fields/) but for me, it is incomplete.

Where should I put the configuration properties as indicated on the official documentation ?
Is there more detailed documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these properties in `etc/cas/config/cas.properties`. You can find this file in your CAS overlay project: https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/blob/master/etc/cas/config/cas.properties

I don't know what your existing config looks like, but these properties might also be declared in other files like `application.properties`.

If you're using only one CAS instance you can use the default `standalone` config options: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.5.x/configuration/Configuration-Server-Management-Standalone.html

However, if you're using multiple (loadbalanced) CAS instances, it might be worth looking into [Spring Cloud](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.5.x/configuration/Configuration-Server-Management-SpringCloud.html).